# How to switch database with Open Liberty on runtime?

Tags: java, maven, open-liberty

I am trying to switch the database host in Open Liberty using the `maven-liberty-plugin` via setting a variable I use in the server.xml.

In my pom.xml I have the following property:

```
<liberty.var.postgres.host>database</liberty.var.postgres.host>
```

In my server.xml I have this (excerpt):

```
<variable name="postgres.host" defaultValue="database"/>

<dataSource id="todoListDS"
            jndiName="jdbc/TodoListDS"
            type="javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource">

    <jdbcDriver id="postgresql-driver"
                javax.sql.XADataSource="org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource"
                javax.sql.DataSource="org.postgresql.ds.PGDataSource"
                javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource="org.postgresql.ds.PGConnectionPoolDataSource"
                libraryRef="postgresql-library"/>

    <properties.postgresql serverName="${postgres.host}"
                           portNumber="${postgres.port}"
                           databaseName="${postgres.database}"
                           user="${postgres.user}"
                           password="${postgres.password}"/>
</dataSource>
```

Then I run my server via: `mvn -Dliberty.var.postgres.host=localhost clean package liberty:run` but the connection seem to fail. I tried the same with the https port and that worked fine. Just the database host does not seem to work.
It works when I change `liberty.var.postgres.host` in the pom.xml to `localhost`.

How can I switch the database host here?

Comment: Your basic approach looks correct to me:  you have a defaultVar  in server.xml , overridden by a regular server.xml var specified in pom.xml, and the value of this regular server.xml var is in turn overridden at the CLI via `-Dliberty.var.postgres.host=localhost`.    You should indeed end up with "localhost".

Comment: The next thing I would do in a case like this is to verify if the Liberty server config is actually what I expect it to be, yet maybe this is still not "correctly" pointing to an actual DB at this config.   E.g. see this blog:  https://openliberty.io/blog/2019/09/13/testing-database-connections-REST-APIs.html.   So add         `<feature>restConnector-2.0</feature>` and an admin user (if you don't have one), e.g. `<quickStartSecurity userName="Bob" userPassword="bobpwd" />`  and hit URL:  https://localhost:9443/ibm/api/config/dataSource/todoListDS.   What does it show for "postgres.host" ?

Comment: If that still looks correct I wonder what version of Open Liberty and liberty-maven-plugin you are using?

Comment: @ScottKurz liberty-maven-plugin 3.2 and Open Liberty 20.0.06. I'll check the restConnector. Good idea.

Comment: Okay, you're right. The database host seem to be fine: ```   "properties.postgresql": {
      "databaseName": "postgres",
      "password": "******",
      "portNumber": 5432,
      "preparedStatementCacheQueries": 0,
      "serverName": "localhost",
      "user": "postgres"
   },```

Comment: @ScottKurz Now it works. I have no idea what has changed. Thanks for all the tips!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the comments on the question for the answer.