# how to debug open liberty datasource issues

Tags: postgresql, datasource, open-liberty

My Open Liberty application doesn't connect to the database. How do I debug the connection settings.

For example the connection fails with:

```
[INFO] Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.8.v20201217-ecdf3c32c4): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
[INFO] Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: The server requested password-based authentication, but no password was provided. DSRA0010E: SQL State = 08004, Error Code = 0
[INFO] Error Code: 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment from [Scott Kurz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62620088/how-to-switch-database-with-open-liberty-on-runtime#comment110745911_62620088) is so brilliant, it should get it's own post:

If you'd like to verify if the Liberty server config is actually what you expect it to be:

See this blog: https://openliberty.io/blog/2019/09/13/testing-database-connections-REST-APIs.html

You need

```
<feature>restConnector-2.0</feature>
```

and an admin user (if you don't have one), e.g.

```
<quickStartSecurity userName="Bob" userPassword="bobpwd" />
```

Now you can see your DB-config: http://localhost:9080/ibm/api/config/dataSource/todoListDS.

For postgres it should look like this:

```
{
   "configElementName": "dataSource",
   "uid": "jpadatasource",
   "id": "jpadatasource",
   "jndiName": "jpadatasource",
   "beginTranForResultSetScrollingAPIs": true,
   "beginTranForVendorAPIs": true,
   "connectionSharing": "MatchOriginalRequest",
   "enableConnectionCasting": false,
   "jdbcDriverRef": {
      "configElementName": "jdbcDriver",
      "uid": "dataSource[jpadatasource]/jdbcDriver[default-0]",
      "libraryRef": {
         "configElementName": "library",
         "uid": "postgresql-driver",
         "id": "postgresql-driver",
         "apiTypeVisibility": "spec,ibm-api,api,stable",
         "filesetRef": [
            {
               "configElementName": "fileset",
               "uid": "library[postgresql-driver]/fileset[default-0]",
               "caseSensitive": true,
               "dir": "/Users/d067570/SAPDevelop/gh/ciaas/api/target/liberty/wlp/usr/shared/resources/",
               "excludes": "",
               "includes": "postgresql-*.jar",
               "scanInterval": 0
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "statementCacheSize": 10,
   "syncQueryTimeoutWithTransactionTimeout": false,
   "transactional": true,
   "properties.postgresql": {
      "databaseName": "postgres",
      "password": "******",
      "portNumber": 5432,
      "preparedStatementCacheQueries": 0,
      "serverName": "localhost",
      "user": "postgres"
   },
   "api": [
      "/ibm/api/validation/dataSource/jpadatasource"
   ]
}
```